# Best design pattern to avoid instanceof when working with classes that cannot be modified?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am overriding a method provided by third-party library class and trying to record exceptions that occur:

```
@Override
someJavaMethod(arg1, arg2, Exception ex){
        //Declare some variables with default values
    if (ex instanceof SpecificException1)
        //Set values for the variables
    else if (ex instanceof SpecificException2)
        //Set some other values for the variables
    else
        //Do nothing
}
```

The issue here is that `SpecificException1` and `SpecificException2` are both third-party exceptions and I cannot modify them.

I understand that using `instanceof` is not a great way to handle this. What design pattern / OO principles I should use to handle this?

(Also, I was advised to see the visitor and acyclic visitor design pattern, but I am not sure if they can be applied to classes that cannot be modified)

Comment: What does your catch clause look like for these exceptions?  Can't you just have some different Java methods depending on what the exception is?

Comment: Visitor patterns won't help you if you can't implement `accept` methods in the element classes.

Comment: Who's calling `someJavaMethod`? Can you give more details about the method you're calling that generates the exception? Adapter might be possible, but more info is needed. Otherwise, couldn't Template method work? The if/then/else block would be an abstract polymorphic method to log the exceptions. With more info I could maybe write up a design as an answer.

Comment: AWS allows attaching an instance of RequestHandler2 with every request. If the request fails, it calls the afterError(Request, Response, Exception) method from the catch block. (We have a lot of such requests and catch blocks)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/handlers/RequestHandler2.html#afterError-com.amazonaws.Request-com.amazonaws.Response-java.lang.Exception-

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no fundamentally different ways of solving this (at least not in Java). If you were using a language that allows for multi-dispatch, you could overload the message for the different exception types.

I would rather suggest to simply accept it. If at all I would see how the clean code rules help here, for example by making sure that each if block goes into a distinct method.

Well, there is one slightly different approach: you could potentially use a map. Keys would be the exception class, the values would be *something* that contains the values for your different variables that need to be assigned.

Comment: So there is no way to get rid of the "if instanceof" clauses if I am doing this in Java? I understand I can clean it beyond that.

Comment: As said, the only other approach would be to use a map with class objects, or to rethrow the exception and use try catch, as outlined in the other answer. For some problems, there simply isnt a great solution, due to the limitations of the language. Been in that spot to, my recommendation: make sure you have good unit tests that test each different exception type. But yes, overall, such code can turn ugly quickly. Finally: please consider accepting an answer at some point.

Answer (score 1):

What about throwing the exception in a try-catch block and using the catch clauses to identify which exception it is?

Comment: Really bad practice. Try catch should not be used for normal control flow. It would definitely surprise most readers, and potentially cost regarding runtime performance.

Comment: @GhostCat Weird questions get weird answers.  Once you start passing exceptions around all bets are off.

Comment: As said, there are good arguments why your answer should not be followed. And arguing that further breaking a broken thing is okay, well, not in my eyes.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the method that the library offers.

Comment: @GhostCat I actually agree with you, but the question was specific to the problem of running case-type logic based on the class of an exception including, perhaps, subclasses of those exceptions that aren't even known or  visible to the code being written. The OP was asking if there's another way to do that without using instanceof and my answer is the only other approach I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Where you get the exception you define a map `Map<String, ExceptionHandler>` and call something like this:

```
Optional.of(stringExceptionMap.get(throwable.getClass().getSimpleName()))
                                 .map(errorHandlers -> errorHandlers.handle(throwable).orElseGet(() ->  whatever));
```

where

```
public interface ExceptionHandler {

    T handle(Throwable throwable);
}
```

have strategies like

```
@Component("WebExchangeBindException")
public class WebExchangeBindExceptionErrorsExtractor implements ErrorsExtractor {

    @Override
    public T handle(Throwable throwable) { ... } 
}
```